# NSPathControl equivalent for iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, nspathcontrol

Is there a control on iOS (iPhone/iPad) that works like NSPathControl does in OSX? (to add dynamically a node to a root on event, that could go back, remove a node on event...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. Shouldn't be too hard to implement one yourself though. You can use standard UIButtons in a custom UIView.